# Reading Comma Delimited Text File to C# DataTable, columns get truncated to 255 characters

Tags: c#, .net, csv, oledb, jet

We are importing from CSV to SQL. To do so, we are reading the CSV file and writing to a temporary .txt file using a schema.ini. (I'm not sure yet exactly why are are writing to this temporary file, but that's how the code currently works).  From there, we are loading a DataTable via OleDB using the following connection string (for ASCII files).

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sPath + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"";
```

The problem we are having is that fields with more than 255 characters get truncated. I've read online about this problem and it seems that by default, text fields get truncated thusly.

I set my registry settings  `ImportMixedTypes=Majority Type` and `TypeGuessRows=0` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel`
, hoping that `mycolumns` will no longer be interpreted as text. After doing that, the temporary txt file is being written correctly from the CSV file, but when I call `dataAdapter.Fill`, the resulting DataTable still has a truncated value.

Here is the column definition in question. 
 
CommaDelimited#txt Notes 2 false 234 true 130 0 0

Any help would be appreciated. At this time, I'm not interested in using any 3d party code to solve this problem, there must be a way using built in tools.

Here is the table definition:

```
<Columns> 
    <TABLE_NAME>CommaDelimited#txt</TABLE_NAME> 
    <COLUMN_NAME>Notes</COLUMN_NAME> 
    <ORDINAL_POSITION>2</ORDINAL_POSITION> 
    <COLUMN_HASDEFAULT>false</COLUMN_HASDEFAULT> 
    <COLUMN_FLAGS>234</COLUMN_FLAGS> 
    <IS_NULLABLE>true</IS_NULLABLE> 
    <DATA_TYPE>130</DATA_TYPE> 
    <CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>0</CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH> 
    <CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH>0</CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH> 
</Columns>
```

Thanks,

Greg

---

I tried editing the schema.ini specifying text with a width, and that did not help (it was set to memo before)

[CommaDelimited.txt]
Format=CSVDelimited
DecimalSymbol=.
Col1=Notes Text Width 5000

Comment: One more thing... here is the column definition

 <Columns>
    <TABLE_NAME>CommaDelimited#txt</TABLE_NAME>
    <COLUMN_NAME>Notes</COLUMN_NAME>
    <ORDINAL_POSITION>2</ORDINAL_POSITION>
    <COLUMN_HASDEFAULT>false</COLUMN_HASDEFAULT>
    <COLUMN_FLAGS>234</COLUMN_FLAGS>
    <IS_NULLABLE>true</IS_NULLABLE>
    <DATA_TYPE>130</DATA_TYPE>
    <CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>0</CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>
    <CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH>0</CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH>
  </Columns>

Comment: You can edit the original post also.

Comment: Greg. you are allowed to edit your original question. It might be better to incorporate your comment into the original question so it doesn't get lost and overlooked down here.

Comment: "I'm not interested in using any 3d party code to solve this problem" - shame, CsvReader (mixed with SqlBulkCopy) would be ideal... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662179#662198

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll take a look at that, but it would take a lot of red tape to incorporate a 3d party dll.

Comment: Could you use TextFieldParser and SQLBulkCopy? 100% Microsoft, no 3rd parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jet database engine truncates memo fields if you ask it to process the data based on the memo: aggregating, de-duplicating, formatting, and so on.

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: Thanks Robert!!! This led me to my answer: we were doing an LTrim and RTrim on the sql select statement for that column, which was causing the truncation.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple class for reading a delimited file and returning a DataTable (all strings) that doesn't truncate strings.  It has an overloaded method to specify column names if they're not in the file.  Maybe you can use it?

Imported Namespaces

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
```

Code

```
/// <summary>
/// Simple class for reading delimited text files
/// </summary>
public class DelimitedTextReader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Read the file and return a DataTable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">File to read</param>
    /// <param name="delimiter">Delimiting string</param>
    /// <returns>Populated DataTable</returns>
    public static DataTable ReadFile(string filename, string delimiter)
    {
        return ReadFile(filename, delimiter, null);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Read the file and return a DataTable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">File to read</param>
    /// <param name="delimiter">Delimiting string</param>
    /// <param name="columnNames">Array of column names</param>
    /// <returns>Populated DataTable</returns>
    public static DataTable ReadFile(string filename, string delimiter, string[] columnNames)
    {
        //  Create the new table
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        //  Check file
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", filename);

        //  Process the file line by line
        string line;
        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default))
        {
            //  If column names were not passed, we'll read them from the file
            if (columnNames == null)
            {
                //  Get the first line
                line = tr.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    throw new IOException("Could not read column names from file.");
                columnNames = line.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            }

            //  Add the columns to the data table
            foreach (string colName in columnNames)
                data.Columns.Add(colName);

            //  Read the file
            string[] columns;
            while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                columns = line.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                //  Ensure we have the same number of columns
                if (columns.Length != columnNames.Length)
                {
                    string message = "Data row has {0} columns and {1} are defined by column names.";
                    throw new DataException(string.Format(message, columns.Length, columnNames.Length));
                }
                data.Rows.Add(columns);
            }
        }
        return data;

    }
}
```

Required Namespaces

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Here's an example of calling it and uploading to a SQL Database:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        TimeSpan tsRead;
        TimeSpan tsTrunc;
        TimeSpan tsBcp;
        int rows;
        sw.Start();
        using (DataTable dt = DelimitedTextReader.ReadFile(textBox1.Text, "\t"))
        {
            tsRead = sw.Elapsed;
            sw.Reset();
            rows = dt.Rows.Count;
            string connect = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connect))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.UploadTable", cn))
            using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                sw.Start();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tsTrunc = sw.Elapsed;
                sw.Reset();

                sw.Start();
                bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.UploadTable";
                bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("Column A", "ColumnA");
                bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("Column D", "ColumnD");
                bcp.WriteToServer(dt);
                tsBcp = sw.Elapsed;
                sw.Reset();
            }
        }

        string message = "File read:\t{0}\r\nTruncate:\t{1}\r\nBcp:\t{2}\r\n\r\nTotal time:\t{3}\r\nTotal rows:\t{4}";
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format(message, tsRead, tsTrunc, tsBcp, tsRead + tsTrunc + tsBcp, rows));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can correct this by correctly specifying your [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx) file.  I believe the two options are to either set the column to a Memo type, or to set the Width > 255.

Comment: the schema.ini gets dynamically generated and the type is memo

[CommaDelimited.txt]
Format=CSVDelimited
DecimalSymbol=.
Col1=Notes Memo

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to create the DataTable directly when reading the CSV file, rather than going through the extra step of writing the data out to a different text file, only to read it back into memory a second time.

For that matter, how are you ultimately getting the data from the DataTable into the SQL database? If you're just looping through the DataTable and doing a bunch of INSERT statements, why not skip **two** middlemen and call the same INSERT statements while you're initially reading the CSV file?

Comment: Good questions all. I'm not that familiar with this code, so I'm trying to figure out why it's doing all this. Our data is very dynamic, so we don't know what it is that we are reading in, so that probably contributes to this need for extra machinery. Right now I"m not looking for a total re-write, just a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is by using CSVReader in the following blog:
http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.com/2008/03/stopping-and-continuing-save-event.html

Comment: I don't see CSVReader mentioned in the cited post. Can you explain how its relevant?

Answer (score -1):

I was facing a similar issue with my .Net code, and i was able to make it work just by changing the Registry settings to Majortity Type as mentioned in the original post. What i did different in my case is:
Since we are trying to import from a CSV and not an Excel. So i had to change the settings for Text in the Registry (Not Excel).

Try doing it and i think it should work